# Multiple Azure tenants joining Global Address List

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, outlook, microsoft-teams

I have an azure Tenant, called domainA.com.

My friend has an azure Tenant called domainB.com.

Is it Possible to have Microsoft Teams and Outlook Global address list, to list my users and his users not as external?
How is it possible to achieve?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/multi-tenant-organizations/cross-tenant-synchronization-overview  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/multi-tenant-organizations/cross-tenant-synchronization-configure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the web search results, this is possible by [enabling cross-tenant synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/multi-tenant-people-search?view=o365-worldwide) that will allow users to be synced to another tenant and be discoverable in its global address list.